# How to remove HTML Entities in Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How to remove HTML Entities using Jsoup? If I use Element.toString(), I get:

```
(...)
       <td>Letter &oacute;</td> //valid: <td>Letter ó</td>
(...)
```

Comment: But I want to get text "Letter ó" in toString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can specify an encoding when you create a Jsoup Document something like this:

```
Document newDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlString, StringUtils.EMPTY, Parser.htmlParser());
newDocument.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.base);
newDocument.outputSettings().charset(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
```

Comment: EscapeMode.base doesn't work with óąś, but I set to xhtml :) Thanks

Comment: you need to play with those settings as you can miss display control chars such as &mdash; for example (if you care of course about those :))

Comment: EscapeMode.base is default

Answer (score 8):

This may be off-topic to the context of your question, but if you want to just decode HTML-entities without any other changes in the string (no tag processing, no comment stripping, etc) you can use [`org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities`](//jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-), e.g.:

```
assert Parser.unescapeEntities("x &asymp; <i>y</i>\n", true)
    .equals("x ≈ <i>y</i>\n");
```